# How to increase or decrease the speed of a gameObject after solving a puzzle?

Tags: unity

I am new to unity development and I am trying to make a script where the game player needs to solve puzzles to keep an object moving. How can I make the player increase/decrease this velocity after solving a challenge? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1

I just started with this code to control a Sphere using the arrows:

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float speed;

private Rigidbody rb;

void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}
```

I am thinking to try a method like velocityIncrease that will act after a condition statement like isPuzzleSolved. My intention is to handle the Sphere after getting some points during the puzzle. It will keeps the ball rolling until it reach its goal. My screen will be divided on a field where the ball stays and on the bottom of the screen I need to put an area for the puzzle solving. Thanks to reply.

Comment: That would help if you could edit your question to add what you have already tried and didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried simply applying a variable `velocity` to your moving object and altering it when solving puzzles?

Comment: "I am thinking to try a method like velocityIncrease that will act after a condition statement like isPuzzleSolved" sounds like a great plan. Want to give this a try, and update your question if you get stuck anywhere along the way?